Magento 2.4.7 - Advice setting up csp
I am trying to get my head around csp after upgrading Magento to 2.4.7. Prior to this, it was disabled. I have installed a custom module successfully and added a csp_whitelist.xml file with the following that I copied off a whitelist on github:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<csp_whitelist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Csp:etc/csp_whitelist.xsd">
    <policies>
        <policy id="default-src">
            <values>
                <value id="data" type="host">'self'</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="base-uri">
            <values>
                <value id="data" type="host">'self'</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="font-src">
            <values>
                <value id="data" type="host">'self' data: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com</value>
                <value id="bootstrapcdn" type="host">*.bootstrapcdn.com</value>
                <value id="fontawesome" type="host">*.fontawesome.com</value>
                <value id="googleapis" type="host">*.googleapis.com</value>
                <value id="gstatic" type="host">*.gstatic.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="style-src">
            <values>
                <value id="data" type="host">'report-sample'</value>
                <value id="data2" type="host">'self'</value>
                <value id="data3" type="host">'unsafe-inline'</value>
                <value id="data4" type="host">https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com</value>
                <value id="bootstrapcdn" type="host">*.bootstrapcdn.com</value>
                <value id="cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
                <value id="fontawesome" type="host">*.fontawesome.com</value>
                <value id="google-apis" type="host">*.googleapis.com</value>
                <value id="gstatic" type="host">*.gstatic.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="img-src">
            <values>
                <value id="data" type="host">'self'</value>
                <value id="adobedtm-assets" type="host">assets.adobedtm.com</value>
                <value id="adobedtm-all" type="host">*.adobedtm.com</value>
                <value id="cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
                <value id="googleadservices" type="host">*.googleadservices.com</value>
                <value id="google-analytics" type="host">*.google-analytics.com</value>
                <value id="vimeocdn" type="host">*.vimeocdn.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="connect-src">
            <values>
                <value id="data" type="host">'self'</value>
                <value id="cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
                <value id="google-maps" type="host">'self' https://maps.googleapis.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="frame-src">
            <values>
                <value id="data" type="host">'self'</value>
                <value id="stripe" type="host">https://js.stripe.com</value>
                <value id="google" type="host">*.google.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="script-src">
            <values>
                <value id="hash" type="hash" algorithm="sha256">W5akSSK6LD5BjIlNICMcXaUObQSRAaj6bs7JHADURBA=</value>
                <value id="hash2" type="hash" algorithm="sha256">3qVqeAdyxxTdPkkRzqapjGkAUYLahxSrB7Mdup+GPQ0=</value>
                <value id="hash3" type="hash" algorithm="sha256">2rvfFrggTCtyF5WOiTri1gDS8Boibj4Njn0e+VCBmDI=</value>
                <value id="hash4" type="hash" algorithm="sha256">p8MCfMHqrovsjRYU9z0bU17dd0z81k/fVbGrtBBiM9g=</value>
                <value id="hash5" type="hash" algorithm="sha256">0pk2s4oXwBELlC6IBVb3nNaM2PjfjwI2N6OGIX5lx8Y=</value>
                <value id="hash6" type="hash" algorithm="sha256">nkEZknO0IxNxY/CkTMBhjNhwPvglpYumjx31B4fjkY8=</value>
                <value id="report-sample" type="host">'report-sample'</value>
                <value id="self" type="host">'self'</value>
                <value id="unsafe-eval" type="host">'unsafe-eval'</value>
                <value id="unsafe-hashes" type="host">'unsafe-hashes'</value>
                <value id="unsafe-inline" type="host">'unsafe-inline'</value>
                <value id="adobedtm-assets" type="host">assets.adobedtm.com</value>
                <value id="adobedtm-all" type="host">*.adobedtm.com</value>
                <value id="adobe" type="host">*.adobe.com</value>
                <value id="avada" type="host">*.avada.io</value>
                <value id="amcglobal" type="host">amcglobal.sc.omtrdc.net</value>
                <value id="braintree-api" type="host">api.braintreegateway.com</value>
                <value id="braintree-sandbox" type="host">api.sandbox.braintreegateway.com</value>
                <value id="braintree-analytics" type="host">client-analytics.braintreegateway.com</value>
                <value id="braintree-analytics-sand" type="host">client-analytics.sandbox.braintreegateway.com</value>
                <value id="braintree-js" type="host">js.braintreegateway.com</value>
                <value id="braintree-assets" type="host">assets.braintreegateway.com</value>
                <value id="cardinalcommerce" type="host">geostag.cardinalcommerce.com</value>
                <value id="cardinalcommerce2" type="host">1eafstag.cardinalcommerce.com</value>
                <value id="cardinalcommerce3" type="host">geoapi.cardinalcommerce.com</value>
                <value id="cardinalcommerce4" type="host">1eafapi.cardinalcommerce.com</value>
                <value id="cardinalcommerce5" type="host">songbird.cardinalcommerce.com</value>
                <value id="cardinalcommerce6" type="host">*.cardinalcommerce.com</value>
                <value id="cardinalcommerce7" type="host">songbirdstag.cardinalcommerce.com</value>
                <value id="commerce-payment8" type="host">*.commerce-payment-services.com</value>
                <value id="cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
                <value id="google-pay" type="host">pay.google.com</value>
                <value id="google-analytics" type="host">*.google-analytics.com</value>
                <value id="google-analytics2" type="host">www.google-analytics.com</value>
                <value id="google-analytics3" type="host">analytics.google.com</value>
                <value id="google-analytics4" type="host">analytics.google.com</value>
                <value id="googletagmanager" type="host">googletagmanager.com</value>
                <value id="googletagmanager2" type="host">www.googletagmanager.com</value>
                <value id="googletagmanager3" type="host">*.googletagmanager.com</value>
                <value id="google-apis" type="host">apis.google.com</value>
                <value id="google-apis2" type="host">*.googleapis.com</value>
                <value id="google-apis3" type="host">www.googleapis.com</value>
                <value id="google-ads" type="host">www.googleadservices.com</value>
                <value id="google-ads2" type="host">googleads.g.doubleclick.net</value>
                <value id="google-ads3" type="host">*.googleadservices.com</value>
                <value id="google-ads4" type="host">googleads.g.doubleclick.net</value>
                <value id="gstatic" type="host">*.gstatic.com</value>
                <value id="google-recaptcha" type="host">https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/</value>
                <value id="google-recaptcha2" type="host">https://www.google.com/recaptcha/</value>
                <value id="google-recaptcha3" type="host">www.google.com/recaptcha/</value>
                <value id="google-recaptcha4" type="host">www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/</value>
                <value id="google-recaptcha5" type="host">https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha</value>
                <value id="google-recaptcha6" type="host">https://www.google.com/recaptcha</value>
                <value id="google" type="host">google.com</value>
                <value id="google2" type="host">*.google.com</value>
                <value id="google3" type="host">*.google.com/</value>
                <value id="google-maps" type="host">https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js</value>
                <value id="includestest" type="host">includestest.ccdc02.com</value>
                <value id="instagram" type="host">*.instagram.com</value>
                <value id="klarna" type="host">klarna.com</value>
                <value id="klarna2" type="host">*.klarna.com</value>
                <value id="klarna3" type="host">*.klarnacdn.net</value>
                <value id="klarna4" type="host">*.klarnaevt.com</value>
                <value id="magento-ds" type="host">*.magento-ds.com</value>
                <value id="newrelic" type="host">*.newrelic.com</value>
                <value id="nr-data" type="host">*.nr-data.net</value>
                <value id="paypal" type="host">www.paypal.com</value>
                <value id="paypal-objects" type="host">www.paypalobjects.com</value>
                <value id="paypal-objects2" type="host">*.paypalobjects.com</value>
                <value id="paypal-t" type="host">t.paypal.com</value>
                <value id="paypal-c" type="host">c.paypal.com</value>
                <value id="paypal-all" type="host">*.paypal.com</value>
                <value id="paypal-sandbox" type="host">www.sandbox.paypal.com</value>
                <value id="paypal-sandbox2" type="host">sandbox.paypal.com</value>
                <value id="paypal-sandbox3" type="host">*.sandbox.paypal.com</value>
                <value id="paypal-t2" type="host">t.paypal.com</value>
                <value id="stripe-js" type="host">https://js.stripe.com/v3/</value>
                <value id="stripe-all" type="host">*.stripe.com</value>
                <value id="stripe-link" type="host">*.link.com</value>
                <value id="typekit" type="host">*.typekit.net</value>
                <value id="typekit2" type="host">use.typekit.net</value>
                <value id="vimeo" type="host">*.vimeo.com</value>
                <value id="vimeo2" type="host">www.vimeo.com</value>
                <value id="vimeo3" type="host">*.vimeocdn.com</value>
                <value id="youtube" type="host">*.youtube.com</value>
                <value id="ytimg" type="host">s.ytimg.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="media-src">
            <values>
                <value id="data" type="host">'self'</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="manifest-src">
            <values>
                <value id="data" type="host">'self'</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="object-src">
            <values>
                <value id="data" type="host">'none'</value>
                <value id="hash" type="hash" algorithm="sha256">W5akSSK6LD5BjIlNICMcXaUObQSRAaj6bs7JHADURBA=</value>
                <value id="hash2" type="hash" algorithm="sha256">3qVqeAdyxxTdPkkRzqapjGkAUYLahxSrB7Mdup+GPQ0=</value>
                <value id="hash3" type="hash" algorithm="sha256">2rvfFrggTCtyF5WOiTri1gDS8Boibj4Njn0e+VCBmDI=</value>
                <value id="hash4" type="hash" algorithm="sha256">p8MCfMHqrovsjRYU9z0bU17dd0z81k/fVbGrtBBiM9g=</value>
                <value id="hash5" type="hash" algorithm="sha256">0pk2s4oXwBELlC6IBVb3nNaM2PjfjwI2N6OGIX5lx8Y=</value>
                <value id="hash6" type="hash" algorithm="sha256">nkEZknO0IxNxY/CkTMBhjNhwPvglpYumjx31B4fjkY8=</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="worker-src">
            <values>
                <value id="data" type="host">'none'</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
    </policies>
</csp_whitelist>

Currently my checkout is not loading, with Chrome's console giving me the following:
checkout/:11 Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src assets.adobedtm.com *.adobe.com www.googleadservices.com www.google-analytics.com googleads.g.doubleclick.net analytics.google.com www.googletagmanager.com *.newrelic.com *.nr-data.net geostag.cardinalcommerce.com 1eafstag.cardinalcommerce.com geoapi.cardinalcommerce.com 1eafapi.cardinalcommerce.com songbird.cardinalcommerce.com includestest.ccdc02.com www.paypal.com www.sandbox.paypal.com www.paypalobjects.com t.paypal.com s.ytimg.com www.googleapis.com *.vimeo.com www.vimeo.com *.vimeocdn.com *.youtube.com https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/ https://www.google.com/recaptcha/ *.commerce-payment-services.com *.typekit.net google.com *.google.com amcglobal.sc.omtrdc.net *.magento-ds.com use.typekit.net js.braintreegateway.com assets.braintreegateway.com c.paypal.com pay.google.com api.braintreegateway.com api.sandbox.braintreegateway.com client-analytics.braintreegateway.com client-analytics.sandbox.braintreegateway.com *.paypal.com songbirdstag.cardinalcommerce.com *.googleapis.com *.gstatic.com *.instagram.com www.google.com/recaptcha/ www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/ *.googleadservices.com *.google-analytics.com *assets.adobedtm.com *googleads.g.doubleclick.net *analytics.google.com *.googletagmanager.com *.cardinalcommerce.com *sandbox.paypal.com *.paypalobjects.com *t.paypal.com *s.ytimg.com https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha https://www.google.com/recaptcha *.google.com/ *.avada.io *.stripe.com klarna.com *.klarna.com *.klarnacdn.net *.klarnaevt.com *.link.com 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-hashes' 'nonce-bWNsY3p4Nmh6Ym8xZ2x3MWw4Y3JzbjM5NmNmbnRmcWQ=' 'sha256-W5akSSK6LD5BjIlNICMcXaUObQSRAaj6bs7JHADURBA=' 'sha256-3qVqeAdyxxTdPkkRzqapjGkAUYLahxSrB7Mdup+GPQ0=' 'sha256-2rvfFrggTCtyF5WOiTri1gDS8Boibj4Njn0e+VCBmDI=' 'sha256-p8MCfMHqrovsjRYU9z0bU17dd0z81k/fVbGrtBBiM9g=' 'sha256-0pk2s4oXwBELlC6IBVb3nNaM2PjfjwI2N6OGIX5lx8Y=' 'sha256-nkEZknO0IxNxY/CkTMBhjNhwPvglpYumjx31B4fjkY8=' local.adguard.org 'nonce-43e183d31a244cc9afdd777d8ef'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-dn3M6MPF4GXog4BRnrw+ns2v/ER5GrnnRTSYtw/47qM='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

checkout/:293 Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src assets.adobedtm.com *.adobe.com www.googleadservices.com www.google-analytics.com googleads.g.doubleclick.net analytics.google.com www.googletagmanager.com *.newrelic.com *.nr-data.net geostag.cardinalcommerce.com 1eafstag.cardinalcommerce.com geoapi.cardinalcommerce.com 1eafapi.cardinalcommerce.com songbird.cardinalcommerce.com includestest.ccdc02.com www.paypal.com www.sandbox.paypal.com www.paypalobjects.com t.paypal.com s.ytimg.com www.googleapis.com *.vimeo.com www.vimeo.com *.vimeocdn.com *.youtube.com https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/ https://www.google.com/recaptcha/ *.commerce-payment-services.com *.typekit.net google.com *.google.com amcglobal.sc.omtrdc.net *.magento-ds.com use.typekit.net js.braintreegateway.com assets.braintreegateway.com c.paypal.com pay.google.com api.braintreegateway.com api.sandbox.braintreegateway.com client-analytics.braintreegateway.com client-analytics.sandbox.braintreegateway.com *.paypal.com songbirdstag.cardinalcommerce.com *.googleapis.com *.gstatic.com *.instagram.com www.google.com/recaptcha/ www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/ *.googleadservices.com *.google-analytics.com *assets.adobedtm.com *googleads.g.doubleclick.net *analytics.google.com *.googletagmanager.com *.cardinalcommerce.com *sandbox.paypal.com *.paypalobjects.com *t.paypal.com *s.ytimg.com https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha https://www.google.com/recaptcha *.google.com/ *.avada.io *.stripe.com klarna.com *.klarna.com *.klarnacdn.net *.klarnaevt.com *.link.com 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-hashes' 'nonce-bWNsY3p4Nmh6Ym8xZ2x3MWw4Y3JzbjM5NmNmbnRmcWQ=' 'sha256-W5akSSK6LD5BjIlNICMcXaUObQSRAaj6bs7JHADURBA=' 'sha256-3qVqeAdyxxTdPkkRzqapjGkAUYLahxSrB7Mdup+GPQ0=' 'sha256-2rvfFrggTCtyF5WOiTri1gDS8Boibj4Njn0e+VCBmDI=' 'sha256-p8MCfMHqrovsjRYU9z0bU17dd0z81k/fVbGrtBBiM9g=' 'sha256-0pk2s4oXwBELlC6IBVb3nNaM2PjfjwI2N6OGIX5lx8Y=' 'sha256-nkEZknO0IxNxY/CkTMBhjNhwPvglpYumjx31B4fjkY8=' local.adguard.org 'nonce-43e183d31a244cc9afdd777d8ef'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-TcUB1mzXiQO4GxpTRZ0EMpOXKMU3u+n/q1WrgVIcs1I='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Can someone kindly advise how to turn that into csp code?

"Did you manage to solve this issue?"

these are inline script issues, they will not be resolved using csp_whitelist.xml. You need to approach your developer or third party extension provider to resolve those issues. This blog article can help understand inline script issue https://www.scommerce-mage.com/blog/magento2-csp-whitelisting.html

I am facing the same issue, are you able to resolve this issue ? please update on this

The error messages you're encountering in Chrome's console indicate that your Content Security Policy (CSP) whitelist is blocking some inline scripts required for your checkout functionality. Let's break down the key points:
Error Message:
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src"
Whitelist Configuration:
You've included a whitelist for various domains and sources in your script-src policy.
You've also added some sha256 hashes, but they seem to be missing corresponding scripts.
Problem:
Inline scripts within your checkout page are referencing resources from domains not explicitly allowed in your script-src policy. This leads to a security restriction by CSP.
Solutions:
Identify Blocked Scripts:
Review the console errors and identify the specific inline scripts causing issues.
These might be referenced by URLs or script tags.
Whitelist Required Sources:
Based on the identified scripts, you have two options:
Domain Whitelisting:  If the scripts reside on specific domains (e.g., assets.adobedtm.com), add them to your script-src policy using the host type:
XML
<value id="adobedtm" type="host">assets.adobedtm.com</value>

Hash Whitelisting:  If the scripts are dynamically generated, you'll need to use the hash type with the appropriate SHA256 hash and encode it later with BASE64:
Generate the SHA256 hash of the script content using online tools or browser developer tools.
https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha256.html
Add the hash value to your script-src policy with sha256 algorithm and make sure output is set to Base64 :
XML
<value id="script-checkout" type="hash" algorithm="sha256">YOUR_SCRIPT_HASH</value>

Important Note:
Avoid unsafe-inline: While tempting, using unsafe-inline in your script-src policy weakens CSP security and should be avoided.
Additional Tips:
Consider minimizing the use of inline scripts. Refactoring them into external scripts or leveraging UI components can improve maintainability and security.
Regularly review and update your CSP whitelist as your checkout functionality evolves.
By following these steps, you should be able to resolve the CSP errors and ensure your checkout page functions properly while maintaining a secure environment. For more information, refer to this blog article which has detailed information about CSP and inline script. Alternatively you can refer to official Adobe Page

In Adobe Commerce and Magento Open Source version 2.4.7 and later, CSP (Content Security Policy) is configured to operate in a restrictive mode by default for payment pages within both the storefront and admin areas. For these payment pages, the CSP header excludes the unsafe-inline keyword in the script-src directive, permitting only whitelisted inline scripts. For all other pages, CSP is set to "report-only" mode. You can adjust the CSP settings in a custom module by modifying the module's etc/config.xml file.
To temporarily get your checkout pages working while you whitelist the necessary external scripts, you can change the CSP mode for checkout pages to "report-only" and disable inline script blocking. Here’s how to do it:
Step 1: Create a Custom Module
Create the module directory structure:
app/code/[Vendor]/[ModuleName]/

Create the registration.php file:
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    '[Vendor]_[ModuleName]',
    __DIR__
);

Create the etc/module.xml file:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="[Vendor]_[ModuleName]" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>

Step 2: Configure CSP in config.xml
Create the etc/config.xml file to set the CSP mode for checkout pages:
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <csp>
            <mode>
                <storefront_checkout_index_index>
                    <report_only>1</report_only>
                </storefront_checkout_index_index>
            </mode>
            <policies>
                <storefront_checkout_index_index>
                    <scripts>
                        <inline>1</inline>
                    </scripts>
                </storefront_checkout_index_index>
            </policies>
        </csp>
    </default>
</config>

Run setup upgrade:
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Deploy static content
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Clear the cache:
php bin/magento cache:clean

https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/security/content-security-policies/

This will solve the CSP issue on the checkout page.

Try the below code inside your custom module's csp_whitelist.xml
Please replace all hash values with your values.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<csp_whitelist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Csp:etc/csp_whitelist.xsd">
        <policies>
            <policy id="object-src">
                <values>
                    <value id="hash" type="hash" algorithm="sha256">B2yPHKaXnvFWtRChIbabYmUBFZdVfKKXHbWtWidDVF8=</value>
                    <value id="hash2" type="hash" algorithm="sha256">B2yPHKaXnvFWtRChIbabYmUBFZdVfKKXHbWtWidDVF9=</value>
                </values>
            </policy>
            <policy id="script-src">
                <values>
                    <value id="adobedtmassets" type="host">assets.adobedtm.com</value>
                    <value id="adobedtm-all" type="host">*.adobedtm.com</value>
                </values>
            </policy>
            <policy id="img-src">
                <values>
                    <value id="adobedtm-assets" type="host">assets.adobedtm.com</value>
                    <value id="adobedtm-all" type="host">*.adobedtm.com</value>
                </values>
            </policy>
        </policies>
</csp_whitelist>


I am facing the same issue with hash on checkout page, are you able to resolve this issue ? please update on this

I have used it in one of our projects, you can try and check it once.

@ian have you tried this solution?

Hello. I have updated my first post with my current csp whitelist contents. I am still getting error messages in my Chrome console, so is there an error on my whitelist? Thanks!

Hi @JigarKarangiya , thank you for your solution involving adding the hash in 'object-src,' which is working fine and has successfully removed the error message from the console. However, the other solution regarding adding 'adobedtm-assets' has had no impact

I will look that issue once get time, best of luck!

It can be long answer, but I will keep it simple so that you understand what needs to be done.
In your policy id script-src:
When you see this error:

checkout/:11 Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src assets.adobedtm.com *.adobe.com www.googleadservices.com www.google-analytics.com googleads.g.doubleclick.net analytics.google.com

This simply means that you need to add a line for assets.adobedtm.com.
<policy id="script-src">
        <values>
            <value id="cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
            ...........
            <value id="graph-facebook" type="host">graph.facebook.com</value>
            <value id="adobe" type="host">assets.adobedtm.com</value>
        </values>
    </policy>

Try this and see if this starts to work.
If you want to make checkout work when you are working out these errors in your staging site:
In your custom module's config.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
  <default>
    <csp>
      <mode>
        <storefront>
          <report_only>1</report_only>
        </storefront>
        <admin>
          <report_only>1</report_only>
        </admin>
      </mode>
    </csp>
  </default>
</config>

Once you are able to whitelist all the external domains, then you can make these <report_only>1</report_only> to <report_only>0</report_only>.

OK. So do I also have to add lines for the rest of the sites in the error, *.adobe.com, www.googleadservices.com and so on?

Yes, that is correct.

Thanks. On examples with www. such as www.googleadservices.com, do I literally put that? Also lines such ashttps://www.google.com/recaptcha/ ? Is there a way they to be formatted? Thanks for your help!

If possible can you also explain what to do with the following: 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-hashes' 'nonce-bWNsY3p4Nmh6Ym8xZ2x3MWw4Y3JzbjM5NmNmbnRmcWQ=' 'sha256-W5akSSK6LD5BjIlNICMcXaUObQSRAaj6bs7JHADURBA=' 'sha256-3qVqeAdyxxTdPkkRzqapjGkAUYLahxSrB7Mdup+GPQ0=' 'sha256-2rvfFrggTCtyF5WOiTri1gDS8Boibj4Njn0e+VCBmDI=' 'sha256-p8MCfMHqrovsjRYU9z0bU17dd0z81k/fVbGrtBBiM9g=' 'sha256-0pk2s4oXwBELlC6IBVb3nNaM2PjfjwI2N6OGIX5lx8Y=' 'sha256-nkEZknO0IxNxY/CkTMBhjNhwPvglpYumjx31B4fjkY8=' local.adguard.org 'nonce-43e183d31a244cc9afdd777d8ef'".

this does not work. I'm also having this issue.

I have added a solution for the 'self' and 'unsafe-eval' which can be whitelisted using keyword-based conditions. Please check and accept the answer if it works.

I am facing the same issue with hash, are you able to resolve this issue ? please update on this

If you have a custom module, you can set the settings of CSP in your config.xml file.
For example, if you want to set everything to "report_only" even on the checkout page, use the following config.xml in your plugin.
<?xml version="1.0"?> <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <csp>
            <mode>
                <storefront_checkout_index_index>
                    <report_only>1</report_only>
                </storefront_checkout_index_index>
                <storefront>
                    <report_only>1</report_only>
                </storefront>
                <admin>
                    <report_only>1</report_only>
                </admin>
            </mode>
            </csp>
    </default> </config>


Thanks but I have already done that. Where I'm stuck now is dealing with browser console errors like: Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src assets.adobedtm.com 'nonce-MDh4bWV0ZWUwM3Q5MGVwZHRvMGllMmNhem1rcHhzdGM=' 'sha256-W5akSSK6LD5BjIlNICMcXaUObQSRAaj6bs7JHADURBA=' 'nonce-fb4b6dd273584690b62038c0e02'". Note that 'unsafe-inline' is ignored if either a hash or nonce value is present in the source list.

Ok, that can also be resolved. In Chrome you can see the exact hash that you have to add. In your case 'W5akSSK6LD5BjIlNICMcXaUObQSRAaj6bs7JHADURBA=', so the string without the sha-256 piece. Add this to your csp_whitelist.xml as follows:
<policy id="script-src">     <values>         <value id="give-this-hash-a-name" type="hash" algorithm="sha256">W5akSSK6LD5BjIlNICMcXaUObQSRAaj6bs7JHADURBA=</value>         ...     </values> </policy>
Repeat this for all messages.

Thanks. However I have also done that and still get the error in my Chrome console?

Ok, that's strange. Did you use the correct hash value for each of the entries? Sometimes there are multiple messages.

Disable CSP content security in magento 2.4.7

module/etc/frontend/events.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_front_send_response_before">
        <observer name="csp_render" instance="Magento\Csp\Observer\Render" disabled="true" />
    </event>
</config>


etc/adminhtml/events.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_front_send_response_before">
        <observer name="csp_render" instance="Magento\Csp\Observer\Render" disabled="true" />
    </event>
</config>

